# Not Working FullScreen API in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, fullscreen

I have button that make FullScreen effect. It work in every browser except Safari.

I try this code, but it hadn't any effect. 
What could be the problem ?

```
document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);

document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullScreen();

document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
```

Whole code look like this http://jsfiddle.net/8yryvoee/1/ it doesnt work in jsfiled, but it work in project on React

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently looking to make Safari 5.1 properly exit (can't test to see how long the original exit works for on slightly newer versions as OS X comes with a much more modern version) though you can try my code. I'll be hooking my Mac up this Saturday (our time zone difference may be greater than 12 hours if you're east of GMT) and I'll make a note to update my code/answer here.

Browsers are *really* picky about *how* you enter fullscreen, mostly they want it to spawn from an event handler so I've included that. Below is pure JavaScript code so there shouldn't be any framework/library requirements. You didn't mention which version of Safari and I can only effectively test a couple currently.

```
function $(o) {var r = false; if (document.querySelectorAll) {r = document.querySelectorAll(o);} return r;}


function editor_fullscreen(e)
{
 e.preventDefault();

 if (document.fullscreen)
 {
  if (document.exitFullscreen) {document.exitFullscreen();}
  else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {document.mozCancelFullScreen();}
  else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {document.webkitExitFullscreen();}
  else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {document.webkitCancelFullScreen();}
  else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {document.msExitFullscreen();}
 }
 else
 {
  if ($('.editor_fullscreen')[0].requestFullscreen) {$('.editor_fullscreen')[0].requestFullscreen();}
  else if ($('.editor_fullscreen')[0].mozRequestFullScreen) {$('.editor_fullscreen')[0].mozRequestFullScreen();}
  else if ($('.editor_fullscreen')[0].webkitRequestFullScreen) {$('.editor_fullscreen')[0].webkitRequestFullScreen();}
  else if ($('.editor_fullscreen')[0].msRequestFullscreen) {$('.editor_fullscreen')[0].msRequestFullscreen();}
  else if (e.target.msRequestFullScreen) {alert('e.targe.parent.parent.parent.parent....');}
  else {console.log('DEveloper: full screen support is not detected; check method letter casing?');}
 }
}


window.onclick = function(e)
{
 $('.fullscreen')[0].onclick = function(e) {editor_fullscreen(e);}
}
```